# How to collect user speech input for global usage?

Tags: bixby

I am looking to pass/store user's speech input. Bixby gives the user a result-view list of items, of which the user will say what item they want. Bixby will then display a list of account names, of which the user will say what account. I want to store what the user says after each list to combine them for an API call later.

Currently, I have only created the lists Bixby displays after each user input, but I do not know how to go forward to use both of the user inputs to use in a API call. My authorization.bxb is all configured and works, it is strictly only being able to forward information from multiple "moments." I have tried creating a input-view using selection-of, but continued to have issues displaying a list.

PossibleDataMetrics.view.bxb

```
result-view {
  match: Metric (metric) {
      from-output: ListMetrics
  }
  message {
    template ("What data metrics are you looking for?")
  }
  render {
    layout {
      section {
        content {
          partitioned {
            content {
              for-each (metric){
                as (m) {
                  title-area {
                    slot1 {
                      text {
                        value ("#{value(m.metrics)}")
                        style (Title_S)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ProfileTitleCardResultView.view.bxb

```
result-view {
  match: Profile (profile) {
      from-output: GetProfiles
  }
  message {
    template ("What profile would you like?")
  }
  render {
    layout {
      section {
        content {
          for-each (profile){
            as (view) {
              title-card {
                title-area {
                  halign (Start)
                  slot1 {
                    single-line {
                      text {
                        style (Detail_L_Soft)
                        value ("Account: #{value(view.acctName)}")
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  slot2 {
                    single-line {
                      text {
                        style (Detail_M_Soft)
                        value ("Web property: #{value(view.webName)}")
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  slot3 {
                    single-line {
                      text {
                        style (Title_S)
                        value ("Profile: #{value(view.viewName)}")
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When these result views are called, I am looking to take the user input from both of these list of results to use in another action to create another list that is based off the user's answer of the initial 2 results.

Comment: We need to see code. We are programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, To navigate away from `result-view` you have the following options

- Use `followup` to pose a question to the user and use the answer to
  navigate away from the `result-view` https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.followup
- Use `on-click` feature of cards https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout-macro-def.content.map-card.on-click

The other way to accomplish the same is by calling an Action that collects these `inputs` which invokes the `input-view` for each of these.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will I be able to pass user's speech as a selection for on-click? It seems that my only option may be your last recommendation or somehow restructuring my capsule.

Comment: on-click is a touch based option, so its not available to pass user's speech. And yes, its possible that input-view is the way to go in your scenario. I'd map out the conversation flow end-to-end and see which of these options works better.

Comment: Thank you, now I know my options.

Comment: I do have a question though. I am trying to use title-cards for an input-view, but there is this note in the reference, "If this card is not inside of the Details mode of a view. Specifically, consider these examples:
If you have this card in an input-view and are using cards to list options for a user to choose, then clicking the card will choose the card and the defined intent is not passed." What does the on-click do if the intent isn't passed?